# How can I reference a download item from a callback function that has its id as parameter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, reference

Scenario: I execute one of the [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) functions and, inside its callback function, I need to get info (other than the `id` of the item) about the `downloadItem` referenced by the `downloadId`. How do I do that, other than using `chrome.downloads.search()` or building my own array to "remember" the items in `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener()` - since, except the latter, almost all the callback functions there take only the `id`, and not the item itself, as a parameter?

I tried (and need something like) `chrome.downloads.downloadItems[id]` to reference it.

Use case scenario: if one needs the `downloadItem`'s `url` or `filename` in the callback functions of other functions than `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener()` (e.g. `chrome.downloads.open()` or any other, for that matter, as the majority reference the items by their `id`s).

A side question, related to this: how do I check that the downloads were triggered by a certain function in my code, considering that in my tests, the order of execution is:

1. `chrome.downloads.onCreated` listener (where I can reference the actual item, see above)
2. then `chrome.downloads.download()` (where I can know where the download request originates in my code, but I can't reference the actual item)
3. then `chrome.downloads.onChanged` listener (when checking for download's completion).

In other words, I need to know where the download was called from in my code, for a particular item, *at the same time* that I can get additional info on the download item (which I can do only in `chrome.downloads.onCreated()` for now, thus my questions here).

I hope I was clear in describing my problem - if not, feel free to ask in the comments, or check the relevant code below (I want to add the download info to the array **only** if the download originated from `queryselected()`, discarding other downloads that might happen during or after this):

```
function queryselected()
    {
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
            elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='element']");
    for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++)
        {
        if (selection.containsNode(elements[i], true))
            {
            chrome.downloads.download
                (
                {url: somearray[i].url, filename: "element" + i + ".el", conflictAction: "uniquify"},
                function(downloadid)
                    {
                    console.log("downloads.download: ", downloadid);
// I can know where the download was triggered here, but
// I can't access the download item (only its id), so I do in the listener below
                    itemstoquery.push({id: downloadid, url: undefined, filename: undefined});
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }

chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener
    (
    function(downloaditem)
        {
        if (downloaditem)
            {
            console.log("downloads.onCreated: ", downloaditem.url);
            for (var i = 0; i < itemstoquery.length; i++)
                {
// I can access the download item here, but
// I can't know if its download was triggered by queryselected() above,
// since this executes BEFORE chrome.downloads.download()'s callback function
// As a result, the if below is never true, so I can't fill the array properly.
                if (downloaditem.id === itemstoquery[i].id)
                    {
                    itemstoquery[i].url = downloaditem.url;
                    itemstoquery[i].filename = downloaditem.filename;
                    console.log("Started downloading: ", itemstoquery[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener
(
    function(downloaddelta)
    {
    if ((downloaddelta.state) && (downloaddelta.state.current === "complete"))
        {
        console.log("downloads.onChanged: ", downloaddelta.id);
        var rf = chrome.downloads.removeFile(downloaddelta.id);
        var eh = chrome.downloads.erase({id: downloaddelta.id});
        }
    }
);
```

Note: I said 'other than `chrome.downloads.search()`' because it seems to me kind of redundant to "search" for a download item with it, since you *already* have its id and you basically work with it. I want to reference the download item *while* downloading it, not afterwards (where the search might have its role).

Comment: "I need to know where the download was called from in my code" - If you want to sort out downloads triggered by your extension, DownloadItem has "byExtensionId" and "byExtensionName" fields.

Comment: @Viller 2: Yeah, I know that the download was called from my extension, but what I need to know is _which function_ inside my extension called it (e.g. queryselected() or other), so that I can perform actions _only_ for the items whose download was initiated by the said function, discarding the rest. Note: I do other downloads later in my extension, and I don't want to process the latter items the same way I do it here.

Comment: You seem to ask for metadata very specific to your application; therefore, the sane approach is indeed maintaining your own data structure.

Comment: @Viller31: Even more so, both `byExtensionId` and `byExtensionName` return 'undefined', for me (I'm testing my extension in Developer Mode in Chrome, if that matters). In fact, `downloaditem` only has a couple of fields filled with data (e.g. `startTime`, `url`, `exists`) - not even the `filename` is filled (ok, that might change with `uniquify`, but still). You can clearly see which fields are filled with data by logging the whole `downloaditem` object in `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener`. There is little for me there that I can use, since even the `url` can be a duplicate (not unique)

Comment: @Xan: What do you mean by 'maintaining my own data structure'? The metadata is not at all specific to my application - every extension developer out there might want to perform certain actions only for the downloads he initiates by, say, a context menu, and discard those actions when he performs other downloads within his extension. Ok, I admit I was a little verbose when asking, but differentiating between the dowloads of the same extension is a legitimate issue, IMHO...

Comment: _"I need to know is which function inside my extension called it"_ is pretty application-specific.

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe I didn't phrase that properly. This could be done in other ways, like having access to downloadItem (not just its id) from other callback functions too, not just the callback function of `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener`. Thus the first part of my question, which refers to referencing the actual downloadItem. Bottom line, I'm not bound to finding out 'which function inside my extension called it', if I can do my thing another way (like being able to reference downloadItem elsewhere too, for example). It doesn't have to be as specific as in the 2nd part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

> I said 'other than chrome.downloads.search()' because it seems to me kind of redundant to "search" for a download item with it,

They clearly say you should do it. It's the only way to get DownloadItem from id.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search

> To get a specific DownloadItem, set only the id field.

Comment: Yeah, I already knew their "recommendation" and read the info on it, otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question. Anyway, I solved the problem by adding the download `id` to my own array in `chrome.downloads.download`, then using my own faster function to get the other info for the id in `chrome.downloads.onChanged`. The `search` method might be too slow to get this job done, especially if you use (like I do) another extension that deletes the download history as soon as they are completed (thus deleting the ids too). This doesn't qualify as an answer though, since it's just a workaround.